# Laravel Class 'Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Providers\TwitchApiServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have no idea why (can't debug, didn't change anything).

When i run `composer update` its giving me this error

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Providers\TwitchApiServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/rafdev.ovh/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                  
  Class 'Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Providers\TwitchApiServiceProvider' not found
```

This is my `config/app.php`

```
<?php

return [

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    'url' => 'http://localhost',

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    'locale' => 'en',

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'log' => 'single',

    'providers' => [

        // default providers here

        Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Providers\TwitchApiServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    'aliases' => [

        // default aliases here

        'TwitchApi' => Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Facades\TwitchApiServiceFacade::class,
        'Form'      => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'HTML'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    ],

];
```

If i missed something important, like showing you the view / controller - let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding to your `composer.json` file `Twittch`, you should run `composer install` to install it. Then  you should add to your `config/app.php` provider `Skmetaly\TwitchApi\Providers\TwitchApiServiceProvider`.

You probably added provider without running `composer install`. So comment this line in `config/app.php`, run composer install and then add the line with this new provider.

Comment: `composer install` gives the same error, like composer would be dependent on that package

Comment: @Rafau In this case, you should try manually removing cache files from `bootstrap/cache`: `compiled.php` (and/or) `services.json`

Comment: After that had to use `composer clearcache`, and `php artisan serve` because i deleted entirely `services.json` file. Right now everything works fine! Thank you!